# Object on canvas - Stanford Breakout - Paddle flies off screen

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing the Stanford Online Java course and I'm having trouble moving the paddle. My `mouselistener` is all hooked up and it's producing values that seem to be correct with what my mouse is doing. I'm subtracting the current position from the last position, which should give me the translate value for my paddle, but something is screwy. When I load it the paddle appears at the bottom of the screen but as soon as the mouse enters the screen the paddle flies off!!

Note - I've included output to console to show the stream of values that should be updating to the X position of the paddle object.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Breakout extends Canvas implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{
    private final int WIN_WIDTH = 500;
    private final int WIN_HEIGHT = 700;
    private final int BRICK_Y_POSITION =  100;
    private final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 10;
    private final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;
    //Create the paddle
    private final int paddleYPosition = 500;
    private int lastX = 0;
    private int currentX = 0;
    brick paddle = new brick(0,paddleYPosition, BRICK_WIDTH+20, BRICK_HEIGHT);

    //Create Canvas object that implements the MouseListener and KeyListener
    public Breakout(){
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setBackground(Color.gray);
    }

    public void makeBricks(Graphics g, Color color, int yPosition){
        int xSpacer = 0;
        int ySpacer = 0;
        int x = 15;

        g.setColor(color);
        for (int j= 0; j<2; j++){
            for (int i=0; i<13; i++){
                g.fillPolygon(new brick (x + xSpacer , yPosition + ySpacer , BRICK_WIDTH , BRICK_HEIGHT));      
                xSpacer+=35;}
            ySpacer+=15;
            xSpacer = 0;
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){         
        makeBricks(g, Color.red, BRICK_Y_POSITION);
        makeBricks(g, Color.orange, BRICK_Y_POSITION+30);
        makeBricks(g, Color.yellow, BRICK_Y_POSITION+60);
        makeBricks(g, Color.green, BRICK_Y_POSITION+90);
        makeBricks(g, Color.cyan, BRICK_Y_POSITION+ 120);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillPolygon(paddle);
        paddle.translate(currentX - lastX, paddleYPosition);
    }       

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}   
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (10 <= e.getX() && e.getX() <=490){
            currentX = e.getX();
            System.out.println(currentX-lastX);
            lastX = currentX;
        }
        repaint();
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Create canvas
        Breakout canvas = new Breakout();
        //Create JFrame to hold the canvas
        JFrame win = new JFrame("Breakout!");
        win.setSize(500,700);

        //Add all of the visual elements to the JFrame window
        win.add(new JLabel("TitledBorder using LineBorder"));
        win.add(canvas);

        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```